# How to reduce the gap between the map and title using rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I have used the below data and the code to color the countries using rworldmap.

```
ddf = read.table(text="country value
     USA    10
      UK    30
  Sweden    50
   Japan    70
   China    90
 Germany   100", header=T)

  library(rworldmap)
  spdf <- joinCountryData2Map(ddf, joinCode="NAME",  
                              nameJoinColumn="country")

  mapCountryData(spdf, nameColumnToPlot="value", catMethod="fixedWidth")
```

The map is looking fine. The problem I am having is to reduce the gap between the map and the title of the map. Also at the bottom I am having a huge space at the end of the map. I would like to reduce both the spaces.

Comment: Reduce the height of your plotting device. The map fills the space available to it, but if the height:width ratio of the window (or, e.g. the png device) is too large you will get white space.

Answer (score 3):

@jbaums is correct, the shape of the plotting device influences how much white space there is around the plot.

There is a function named `mapDevice()` in `rworldmap` that has default values that work well for plotting world maps.

Using RStudio in windows I put this before your code :

```
mapDevice("x11")
```

to create the plot below. (x11 is a windows graphics device, away from windows `mapDevice()` may work )

[image]

An alternative option is to reduce any margin whitespace by putting this before your code:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,1,0)) #(bottom, left, top, right)
```

Comment: par(mar = c(0,0,0,0),  pty = "m",xaxs = "r", xaxt = 's', xpd = NA, yaxs = "i",
       yaxt = 's')

using pty = 'm' solved the problem for me..